# poetry not involving inner package inside source while exporting

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-poetry

I have pyproject.toml file which contains:

```
packages = [{ include = "my_package", from = "src" }]
```

I want to deploy the project to docker so actually exporting the packages into requiremnt.txt

But after deploying I'm getting

> no module named my_package

Have gone through questions and document and have tried

```
poetry export --format requirements.txt --output poetry-requirements.txt --without-hashes --with dev
```

But still no luck and no any other option given on : https://python-poetry.org/docs/1.4/cli#export

can anyone help on this

format of pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = xxx
version = xxx
description = xxx
authors = xxx
license = xxx
readme = xxx
repository = xxx
documentation = xxx
packages = [
    { include = "my_package", from = "src" }
]


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = xxx
url =xxx

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
xxx
xxx


[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
xxx
xxx

[tool.poetry.extras]
docs = xxx

[tool.poetry.scripts]
abc = xxx.xxx


[tool.coverage.run]
parallel = true
branch = true
data_file = ".coverage/.coverage"

[tool.black]
line-length = 100
preview = true
target-version = ['py310']
include = '\.pyi?$'


[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
line_length = 100

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Folder structure:

```
my-package
  |
  |-pyproject.toml
  |--src
      |--my_package
```

Comment: Can u share more of the yaml and structure of the code? I ran your command on  a project similar and it works fine

Comment: Hi @ozs, Thanks for helping.... have include my pyproject.toml structure and folder structure

Comment: Does my_pavkage have any sibling that use it (under src)?